# PIL ImageGrab returns 24-bit image instead of 32-bit

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following function:

```
def take_screenshot(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2)) 
    return img
```

When I save the image using:

```
img = take_screenshot(10, 10, 200, 200)
img.save("test.png")
```

I thought Pill used 32-bit as default for everything. I don't understand how it can be saved as 24-bit instead of 32-bit.

Comment: Which os are you working on?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.PIL.ImageGrab.grab)
`PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)` Take a snapshot of the screen. The pixels inside the bounding box are returned as an **“RGB” image on Windows or “RGBA” on macOS**.

You can also take a look at source code [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/5.1.x/src/PIL/ImageGrab.py#L32)

On windows, it strictly [uses](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/5.1.x/src/PIL/ImageGrab.py#L40https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/5.1.x/src/PIL/ImageGrab.py#L40) RGB (24-bit)
size, data = grabber()

```
im = Image.frombytes(
        "RGB", size, data,
        # RGB, 32-bit line padding, origin lower left corner
        "raw", "BGR", (size[0]*3 + 3) & -4, -1
        )
```

If it is a requirement to have a 32-bit image, you can convert the image to RGBA (32-bit) using

```
img = take_screenshot(10, 10, 200, 200)
img = img.convert("RGBA")
img.save("test.png")
```

Comment: Is there any way to save screenshots as 32-bit on Windows? All my other functions will not work otherwise :/

Comment: This did the trick. All my functions do still work because of this.